# How to avoid using pwd and urllib to avoid vulnerabilities

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am using `pwd` and `urllib` modules in my code and apparently they are a threat. https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/security/ten-malicious-libraries-found-on-pypi-python-package-index/

I am using pwd only for getting the user id and group id:

```
    uid = pwd.getpwnam('myuser').pw_uid
    gid = pwd.getpwnam('myuser').pw_gid
```

Is there any alternative I can use to get this information without using pwd.

Also I am urllib only for urlretrieve

`_, headers = urllib.urlretrieve(artifactory_url, output_file)`

Is there any alternative to this?

I am using python 2.7

Comment: You misunderstood the article. Assuming that what you are using as `pwd` and `urllib` are legitimate, there is no problem. The problem is that there are malicious packages which trick users to install them by having similar names as legitimate packages.

Comment: @mkrieger1 `pwd`, specifically, was removed

Comment: Unrelated, but if you are truly worried about "vulnerabilities" you need to get off Python 2.7 and onto Python 3. There's only 2 weeks left of support for Python 2.

Comment: HCL appscan still reports using pwd as high risk package.